# Javascript Rewrite Webpage on the Fly

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I have a webpage that looks like this;

```
<HTML><HEAD><META http-equiv="Refresh" content="1"></HEAD><BODY><H3>
DataIneed:   ##.## XX<br>
DataIneed2: ##.## XX
</H2></BODY></HTML>
```

I need a script I can run on the host computer preferably from inside an html file, that will grab the ##.## after DataIneed: and DataIneed2: (which are numbers formatted like this 
-50.00 
22.75

I do not have control of the site above it is generated from a device and I cannot change it, but all I want is to grab the numbers it generates, and throw them into a webpage I design.

I am trying to do this without having to install any addition software as they would all have to go through a long accreditation process to be allowed on the company network.

I am thinking JavaScript will be my answer, but I'm not sure how to go about this.
I have looked on the web, seems to be that I am doing "screen scraping" or "web scraping" but most of the projects I have seen are fine with installing extra software, and also are geared towards actually scraping data off of webpages in bulk.

Comment: FWIW, you have `<H3>` closed by `</H2>`.

Comment: I just googled the expansion for FWIW! Tks.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's bad HTML, but I didn't write the page and I can't change it (one of the reasons I want to be able to scrub it and insert the info I need into my own page).  It's coming from a piece of hardware that I don't have access to, and I use it for monitoring.